# where to save program on computer

Tags: wacom

I have problem puting my wacom pen in action. cannot configure it through the usual wacom pen tablet window. i tried to reinstalling the program, downloaded program WacomTablet_6.3.16-2.exe and it was automaticly saved on my desktop(!?). I don't want to move it without confirmation to program files, and/or to program files (x86).
Since i cannot configure my pen i'm guessing this could be one of the reasons i don't get the usual dialog window for pressure and other configuration.
Help? please!
tnx!

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking here, I assume you are using Ubuntu.
The mayor difference from Window$ is, that Ubuntu does **not** natively work with .exe files and has no Program Files folder (btw, simply copying program there would not in W$ neither)

Thus, if the Wacom tablet coniguration, which is built-in in Ubuntu, does not work for you, try to find package dedicated to linux (usually has .deb).

This page may help you finding and installing desired Wacom drivers
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

Answer (score 0):

The latest Wacom Linux Drivers are available at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads

Also it is helpful if you say which Wacom Tablet you are using

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 056a:0315 Wacom Co., Ltd
```